# Am unable to identify why my program isnt getting compiled

Tags: c

So essentially I intended this program to print log x (base y) if the user inputs x and y using the relation log x/log y = log x (base y) but due to an error the program isnt getting compiled can someone help me find the source of error?

This is my code:

```
    #include <math.h>
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
     int x, y;
    printf("Input value for x: ");
    scanf("%i",x);
    
    printf("Input value for y: ");
    scanf("%i", y);
    
{
    float p;
    p = (log2 x)/(log2 y);
    printf("%d",p);
}
    
    


    return 0;
}
```

This is the error it shows:

```
gcc /tmp/wQQBiIgqJ2.c -lm
/tmp/wQQBiIgqJ2.c: In function 'main':
/tmp/wQQBiIgqJ2.c:9:13: warning: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
    9 |     scanf("%i",x);
      |            ~^  ~
      |             |  |
      |             |  int
      |             int *
/tmp/wQQBiIgqJ2.c:12:13: warning: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
   12 |     scanf("%i", y);
      |            ~^   ~
      |             |   |
      |             |   int
      |             int *
/tmp/wQQBiIgqJ2.c:16:14: error: expected ')' before 'x'
   16 |     p = (log2 x)/(log2 y);
      |         ~    ^~
      |              )
/tmp/wQQBiIgqJ2.c:16:23: error: expected ')' before 'y'
   16 |     p = (log2 x)/(log2 y);
      |                  ~    ^~
      |                       )
/tmp/wQQBiIgqJ2.c:16:17: error: invalid operands to binary / (have 'double (*)(double)' and 'double (*)(double)')
   16 |     p = (log2 x)/(log2 y);
      |         ~       ^
      |         |       |
      |         |       double (*)(double)
      |         double (*)(double)
/tmp/wQQBiIgqJ2.c:17:14: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
   17 |     printf("%d",p);
      |             ~^  ~
      |              |  |
      |              |  double
      |              int
      |             %f
```

Comment: Code should be copied directly into the question *as text*, not a picture of text.  Also, please cut and paste the exact error message you get from the compiler.

Comment: srry will do thnx!

Comment: Also, look at how you're calling `printf` and `scanf`, then look at how you're calling `log2`.  Notice a difference?

Comment: https://manual.cs50.io/ In this website though they have mentioned that log2 exists in math.h

Comment: You missed the point. A function is not called like this `log2 x` but like this `log2(x)`

Comment: oh ok got it! thnx a lot! will try that

Comment: `scanf("%i",x);` also needs to be `scanf("%i",&x);`. Same for the other `scanf`.

Comment: `printf("%d",p);` needs to be `printf("%f",p);`

Answer (score 0):

Scanf funtion format:

```
scanf("%i",&x);
```